# insert record into the specific position when column has identity property

Tags: sql

this is my sample table

with ID as primary key with identity(1,1) and CustomerName column

```
ID         CustomerName
1          Name1
2          Name2
4          Name4
5          Name5
7          Name7
```

I want to insert records 'Id' as '3' with CustomerName as 'Name3' and Id 6 into the table with CustomerName 'Name6'.Is it possible

---

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` in this scenario.

Just set `SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON`

then write your insert statement

then don't forgot to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable  ON

GO

insert into YourTable(ID,Name) values (3,'Name3')

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF
```

See Details [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into yourtablename(ID, CustomerName)
values("3", "name3");
insert into yourtablename(ID, CustomerName)
values("6", "name6");
```